# Time Drop Down list in Excel

Tags: excel, validation, drop-down-menu, time, intervals

I am trying to create a drop down validation in Excel with Time Intervals. Currently it has duration of 5 minutes, i.e. 08:00:00, 08:05:00, 08:10:00 etc. till 9 PM. I need to keep only 10 minutes intervals(08:00, 08:10, 08:20) with the exception of 00:15:00 and 00:45:00 in the list (these need to be included as well).

How do I do that?

Comment: Any help on this one?

Comment: So basically you want a time Dropdown that goes 7:00,7:10,7:15,7:20,7:30,7:40,7:45,7:50,8:00,8:10 should all hours be included or is there some Kind of rule for them too

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to have a hidden column with the time values you wish to show, select List as your data validation (Data - Data Validation - Settings), and select the range of values in your hidden column. Might also want to make the column protected.